# Объясните, пожалуйста, про Array.prototype.filter.call()

Tags: javascript

```
var testElements = document.getElementsByClassName('test');
var testDivs = Array.prototype.filter.call(testElements, function(testElement {
    return testElement.nodeName === 'DIV';
});
```

Есть такой кусочек кода, который отстортировывает все div'ы. Мне непонятно:

1. Почему вызываетcя прототип Array.prototype, а не просто testElements.filter(...). Это потому, что Array.prototype преобразует testElements в массив или почему?

Answer (score 6):

Возвращаемые элементы имеют тип, отличный от массива. Это - так называемая коллекция. Чтобы иметь возможность с ней работать, как с массивом, вам необходимо преобразовать ее в массив.

Преобразовать в массив можно любой объект, у которого ключи приводятся к целочисленному типу и есть свойство length, содержащее индекс последнего элемента + 1.

1. Потому, что testElements - не массив, у него нет метода `filter`.
   `Array.prototype` ничего не преобразует. Он указывает на то, что нужно обратиться к методу `filter` прототипа конструктора `Array`, а не к методу `filter` самого `testElements`.
2. А это - вторая часть. `call` в качестве первого аргумента принимает контекст, в котором будет исполнен метод (то, чему внутри будет равен `this`). Таким образом вы говорите этой строкой

   `Array.prototype.filter.call(testElements)`

   "Позаимствуй у `Array.prototype` метод `filter` и вызови его на псевдомассиве `testElements`".

Кстати, аналогичного поведения можно добиться так:

```
[].filter.call(testElements);
```

В этом случае интерпретатор сначала будет искать метод `filter` у самого объекта (массива), там он его не найдет и продолжит искать по ссылке `__proto__`, которая указывает на тот же `Array.prototype`. Но все-таки первый вариант предпочтительнее, потому как там не происходит инициализация нового массива, пусть даже и пустого.

Comment: Дополню, что из полученной коллекции можно сделать массив с помощью `Array.from( testElements )` и у него появятся все доступные для массивов методы, в том числе и `filter`.

Comment: @ivan.posokhin да можно и по старинке - тем же слайсом.

Answer (score 6):

[`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) - возвращает не массив, а [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection). У полученного объекта **нет** метода `filter`.

В свою очередь метод `filter` - это обобщенный метод, и его можно применять не только к массивам, но и к объектам у которых есть свойство `length`, которое является числом больше 0.

Для того, чтобы применить этот метод не к массиву, его нужно получить отдельно и вызывать у него метод [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), который устанавливает в качестве контекста переданный объект

Comment: "гениальные ответы скорее всего пересказанные хелпы, так как вних напрочь отсутствует человеческий опыт, который так не хватает новичкам." (c) OlmerDale  :D