# Как перевести в верхний регистр случайно выбранные символы в строке?

Tags: javascript

Например, имеется строка

```
var fff = "машина";
```

Необходимо произвести над ней такую операцию, чтобы из строки `"машина"` получилась строка, например, `"МаШиНа"`.

```
var eee = fff.toUpperCase();
console.log(eee); // чтобы выдавало например МаШиНа
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
// изначальная строка
var str = "машина";

// вызываем метод map (который имеется у массивов) на строке
str = Array.prototype.map.call(str, (letter) => {
    // шанс 50%, что буква будет в верхнем регистре
    return Math.random() > .5 ? letter.toUpperCase() : letter;
    // при помощи join соединяем массив обратно в строку
}).join("");

console.log(str);
```

[Про заимствование методов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/736200/200881);
[Метод `map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map);
[Метод `join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

Comment: спасибо , а как его можно сюда добавить вместо toLowerCase()? в функцию если не сложно

Comment: @recile вы аналогичный вопрос недавно задавали, возьмите идею оттуда, а приведенный мной код просто оберните в функцию.